# LINQ c# Условие внутри сортировки

Tags: c#, list, linq

Сортирую список и нужно указать условие что-то вроде если "поле" == null, то сортируй по "поле2", если нет то сортируй по "поле". Как я понял конструкция ()?: в нутри Linq не работает. Вот мой набросок:

```
var sortList = dataList.OrderByDescending(s => s.Status.Value == Status.Yellow)
            .ThenByDescending(s => s.Status.Value == Status.Green)
            .ThenByDescending(s => s.Status.Value==Status.Grey|| s.Status.Value ==Status.White|| s.Status.Value == Status.Snow)
            .ThenByDescending(s=>s.DrStartOnSchedule)
            .ThenByDescending(s=>s.StartTn)
            .ThenByDescending(s => s.WaitingOnSchedule)
            .ThenBy(s=>(s.WaitingOnSchedule==Null)?s.Name:s.WaitingOnSchedule)
            .ToList<MonitorModel>();
        return sortList;
```

Comment: А какие типы имеют `s.Name` и `s.WaitingOnSchedule`? Обе ветви тернарного оператора должны возвращать один и тот же тип

Comment: Не относится к делу, но конструкции вроде `OrderByDescending(s => s.Status.Value == Status.Yellow)`  выглядят странновато

Comment: Вообще плохо понятно что вы хотите сделать, сортировка — это же про множество строк, поэтому у одной может быть `WaitingOnSchedule==Null`, а у другой — нет, как они между собой должны быть отсортированы?

Comment: «конструкция ()?: в нутри Linq не работает» — почему это вдруг? В LINQ-to-objects вполне работает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Реализуйте для вашего класса интерфейс [`IComparable<T>`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.icomparable-1.compareto?view=netframework-4.7.2), метод которого и будет осуществлять нужную логику. В итоге при попытке сортировки через LINQ он будет использовать ваш метод